# Error Message : minternal.h not found

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have one winforms application in c#, which is calling c++/cli(i.e. A lib) library.  In A lib constructor I am calling another c++/cli(i.e. B lib) library.
IN debug mode when I try step into from the winforms application I get the message minternal.h not found.

> Locating source for 'f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\h\minternal.h'. Checksum: MD5 {bb e6 9 f8 47 f4 bb c0 f8 db 78 bf e1 b2 2f 2b}
>   The file 'f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\h\minternal.h' does not exist.

c# Application code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        libinterprocess.Class1 cls1 = new libinterprocess.Class1();
    }
}
```

libinterprocess code (c++/cli : A lib)

```
libinterprocess::Class1::Class1()
{
    testlib::Class1^ cls1 = gcnew testlib::Class1();
}
```

testlib code (c++/cli :B lib)

```
namespace testlib
{
    Class1::~Class1()
    {
        int p = 0;
        p ++ ;
    }

    Class1::Class1()
    {
        int p = 0;
        p++;
    }
}
```

C++/cli libs dos not contain any other include directories or libraries.

call stack information

> testlib.dll!::RegisterModuleUninitializer(System::EventHandler^ handler) Line 299 + 0xf bytes   C++

Environment information
OS : Win 10
Visual Studio 2015

I also tried to repair visual studio. Same situation.

For full error message please see the screen shot.

[image: Error Message]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks for reply. Actually I am working on some c++/cli libs. I want to debug that files. Whenever I tried to step into (debug) lib A constructor (which is calling lib B constructor), I get this error. I have repro code ready (It is similar to code posted in question). Is there any way I can attach source code with question?

Comment: @HansPassant, I just want to debug the c++/cli libs. It's really weird behaviour. Can I send you repro code in your mail?  So you can take a look. repro code is really small in size and very simple. For me it's look like vs2015 problem but not sure. Can you please help me?